# Mistake with MongoDB Queries - Arrays - Loop For

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made this code today, and i don't nkow what's the problem? In theory, the findOne() function should work for() each loop of the for. And this is not that what happen. In the array there are several elements, and i want to save all of this. I'm newbie in NodeJS, but the loop for() always is the same, or not?

```
var sType = models.Type; // Model Mongoose
    var word = ''; // Word
    var i = 0;

    for( i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++ ){
        word = arrayData[i]; // Save the element in word, I made this to try to pass the variable.
        sType.findOne({ nameType: word }, { _id : 1 }, function( err, type ){
            console.log( word ); // In the console, show me the last element of array x20.
            if( err )
                throw err;
            if( !err && type == null ){
                var types = new sType({
                    nameType: word
                });

                types.save( function( err ){
                    if( err )
                        throw err;          
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

If I don't create the variable 'word', the program throw me a mistake 'Validation Error: Path 'nameTYpe' is required.'

Answer (score 0):

If you use the method findOne inside a loop, you need to wait the callback, try to use the library [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async),

here is an example:

```
async.eachSeries(arrayData, function(data, dataCallback) {

  sType.findOne({}, {}, function( err, type ) {
   //your code after the findOne method

   //return to the next element of array
   dataCallback();
  }
}, function done() {
   console.log("loop end");
});
```